# set Field in current item not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a small issue with my workflow. I have a workflow with 3 stages. The workflow sends email for change in status but it does not update the flag value.

I will post the picture of workflow below.

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me with this simple problem?

Comment: does your workflow remain in "In Progress" or "Completed" or "Error" state ?

Comment: no my workflow is in completed stage. When i edit the item again then only the flag value changes not on first edit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `Set field to value` **inside** the scope of the second **IF** condition as shown below

[image]

Comment: i have tried that it is still not working but i will still give it a look

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the workflow sends email for change in status but it does not update the flag value.

Which flag value not be updated? Flag(UAT) or Flag(RorC)?

What is the column type of the Flag(UAT) or Flag(RorC)? Please expand the steps "set Field in current item action".

Comment: Flag UAT is not updated. Flag UAT is a dropdown with yes/no value, no being the default value.